# custom attribute routing with suffix

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing, routeattribute

i want to create my url like this:

```
www.example.com/Content/page.html
```

on top of my ContentControler I use:

```
[RoutePrefix("Home")]
```

and on top of my index action I use:

```
[Route("page.html")]
```

but when I request this url this error will happen:

```
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
```

how i can solve this problem?
thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your `web.config` to get this working. Add in the line below:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
</system.webServer>
```

Further information on what this does here: http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/modules